# Label with fixed x & y inside tableView.cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to make a label for comment for each cell in tableView .. the problem is the label everytime change the "y" position if I change the text string.

I use CGSize to calculate the text string size for width & height .. so if the comment is too long the y will be more bottom .. if the comment is too short also the y changed.

How could I fix x & y for every size of text string. here is my code:

```
static CGFloat messageTextSize = 14.0;

+(CGFloat)maxTextWidth {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return 220.0f;
    } else {
        return 400.0f;
    }
}

+(CGSize)messageSize:(NSString*)message {
    return [message sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:messageTextSize] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake([FirstViewController maxTextWidth], CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *text = @"After a power struggle with the board of directors in 1985, Jobs left Apple and founded NeXT, a computer platform development company specializing in the higher-education and business markets. In 1986, he acquired the computer graphics division of Lucasfilm, which was spun off as Pixar.[13] He was credited in Toy Story (1995) as an executive producer. He served as CEO and majority shareholder until Disney's purchase of Pixar in 2006.[14] In 1996, after Apple had failed to deliver its operating system, Copland, Gil Amelio turned to NeXT Computer, and the NeXTSTEP platform became the foundation for the Mac OS X.[15] Jobs returned to Apple as an advisor, and took control of the company as an interim CEO. Jobs brought Apple from near bankruptcy to profitability by 1998";
    CGSize textSize = [FirstViewController messageSize:text];
   // NSLog(@"%f",textSize.width);
    return 460 + (textSize.height - 100);

}
```

And this the label:

```
   NSString *comment = @"After a power struggle with the board of directors in 1985, Jobs left Apple and founded NeXT, a computer platform development company specializing in the higher-education and business markets. In 1986, he acquired the computer graphics division of Lucasfilm, which was spun off as Pixar.[13] He was credited in Toy Story (1995) as an executive producer. He served as CEO and majority shareholder until Disney's purchase of Pixar in 2006.[14] In 1996, after Apple had failed to deliver its operating system, Copland, Gil Amelio turned to NeXT Computer, and the NeXTSTEP platform became the foundation for the Mac OS X.[15] Jobs returned to Apple as an advisor, and took control of the company as an interim CEO. Jobs brought Apple from near bankruptcy to profitability by 1998";

    CGSize textSize = [FirstViewController messageSize:comment];
UILabel *label6 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 330, cell.frame.size.width - 30, textSize.height)];
    label6.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:61.0/255.0 green:113.0/255.0 blue:154.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    label6.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label6.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:11];
    label6.numberOfLines = 0;
    label6.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap;
    label6.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@",username,comment];
    [cell addSubview:label6];
```

Here you can see screenshot to get the point.. I want to fix the comment under likes label or lets say the starting position is customized

http://d.pr/i/RBid

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using a UITextView and not UILabel, as labels are thought to be one-liners.
2. Make sure you use the same string, font, font-size and wrapping in the size calculation and your TextView.

Comment: Here the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767913/uilabel-with-fixed-width-and-flexible-height Thanks all

Comment: I disagree because other users reading this here will not know what the problem was. Your linked "solution" is essentially point 2 of my answer. A change of 3 lines would have fixed your code.